# How to change player's displayname?

Tags: java, minecraft-fabric

I'm making a client-side mod and need to change the display name (name that hovers over the player's head) For reference: I need to change the names of other players (that do not use the mod), NOT my name that other players see.

I've already looked through all related classes on the net. Minecraft. client. But haven't found anything that renders the display name.

If anyone has any idea about that class, tell me, please. I've spent three days looking for it with no results.

Comment: In nms' `EntityPlayer` there should be some field for player's username/display name, which would be referenced when the server builds the [PlayerInfoUpdate packet](https://wiki.vg/Protocol#Player_Info_Update). If there's nothing there to intercept that packet when the client receives it, then that would be a good point to hook into. Otherwise, you can intercept where the player information is stored.

Comment: 1) Isn't there a method/class that actually renders name? When you disable HUD display name also disappears, but I've found no reference in net.minecraft.client.gui.hud.InGameHud
2)Thanks for help, will try to use this method